# Getting rid of windows 10 from dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

How can I completely uninstall Windows 10 from a dual boot with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

When you are running Ubuntu, you can easily destroy the whole Windows partition and repair the grub menu.
First, install "gparted"

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Open it, and find your Windows partition. Now you can simply delete it or reformat it in order to use it from Ubuntu (if you wanted to extend your actual Ubuntu partition, you would have to do it from USB/liveCD).

After confirming changes, open terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type

```
sudo update-grub
```

in order to restore grub.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to boot using live USB/DVD.
2. Once booted in, try to use gparted to delete the Windows partition.
3. I will say don't delete the recovery partition in case you change
   your mind in future to reinstall Windows.
4. Then resize your Linux partition and take away the left out place of
   Windows.
5. Apply the changes.
6. Then `sudo update-grub`

You should be good to go.

Comment: It's always possible (and likely) that Windows partition is before Ubuntu partitions in terms of location on HDD. In this scenario, will this answer still work? I don't think you can resize any partition at the "beginning" of the partition?

Comment: Using gparted one can use the resize pointer to move the Linux partition to the far left. If recovery partition is in between...one need to move that first to make contiguous space for Linux partition.